# Add CodedUI to Test Manager

Tags: ui-automation, microsoft-test-manager

I have a CodedUI project to automation test. I want to add this CodedUI to Test Manager (or call CodedUI from Test Manager).

I've created this project and build .dll, but I cannot call them from Test Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a test case in Microsoft Test Manager
2. Open Visual Studio and open the coded UI project with the tests you've built
3. Using the same instance of TFS and VS, open the test case within Visual Studio
4. Navigate to the Associated Automation Tab and under Automated Test Name, Click the ...
5. You're list of available test should now be displayed, click a codedUI test and click ok

Coded UI test should now be associated with the test case and be available within MTM.

Next you need to create a build within TFS and associated that build with your Project within MTM

Comment: Thanks @JeffX, I'm following the steps at [http://www.ranorex.com/blog/running-ranorex-automated-tests-using-microsoft-test-manager](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/running-ranorex-automated-tests-using-microsoft-test-manager). Currently, I don't know how call codedui from MTM so I've asked you, I'll implement follow your instruction. Are you any advices for me?

Comment: Once a codedui test is linked to a test case you simple run the test case in the Test tab of MTM. This will run the test in the machine you have your test agent installed on.

Answer (score 1):

1.Generate a build definition for your solution(It can be done in TFS)
2.Associate your automation test case with functional test case (It can be done in TFS)
3.Now think where you want to run your script (Virtual machine or local machine)
4.Now install test agent in that system and connect it to TFS
5.Open MTM and go to LAB management and bring that system into your lab Env.
6.Link your build definition 
So now we have a test case linked with automation test case ,build definition so our solution and lab env set up .Now we can run from MTM and test case will be run in virtual machine where agent has been set up